# FFmpeg won't encode at Main10@L5.1

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding, h.265

I've been messing around with Topaz's Video AI enhancer, and I've been trying to encode the png files the AI outputs via FFMpeg.
It works fine so far, aside from that the exports I'm getting are showing as Main10@L5@Main, not Main10@L5.1@Main in mediainfo.

I'd really appreciate if a more experienced encoder/FFmpeg user could please check over my command line to make sure that I haven't made any mistakes.
A theory I have is that FFMpeg is auto selecting the encoder level and is overriding my settings, but I'm really not sure.

Here is the code in question:
`ffmpeg -r 23.97602 -f image2 -s 3840x2160 -i %6d.png -vcodec libx265 -preset medium -profile main10 -level 5.1 -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24000/1001 -c:a copy Film.mkv`

I'd prefer to have 5.1@High too if that's possible, though I'm not sure if that matters with 23.976fps 4k SDR content.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/372625-ffmpeg-does-not-apply-parameters-with-libx265), we have to set `-x265-params` instead of using `-preset` (the preset overrides some of the defined parameters).

According to [this post](https://ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.narkive.com/3VzHkRzQ/ffmpeg-x265-profile-main10), for selecting `main10` profile, we need to set `-pix_fmt yuv420p10le`.

---

Sample command:

`ffmpeg -y -r 23.97602 -i %6d.png -vcodec libx265 -profile:v main10 -x265-params "level=5.1:high-tier=1:crf=20" -pix_fmt yuv420p10le Film.mkv`

---

Output of MediaInfo:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : HEVC
Format/Info                              : High Efficiency Video Coding
Format profile                           : Main 10@L5.1@High
Codec ID                                 : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Duration                                 : 25 s 25 ms
Bit rate                                 : 5 507 kb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 160 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.028
Stream size                              : 16.4 MiB (98%)
Writing library                          : x265 3.5+9-bf91444e0:[Windows][GCC 10.2.0][64 bit] 10bit
Encoding settings                        : cpuid=1111039 / frame-threads=3 / numa-pools=8 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=3840x2160 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=51 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=3 / no-allow-non-conformance / no-repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-eob / no-eos / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / no-temporal-layers / open-gop / min-keyint=23 / keyint=250 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=4 / b-adapt=2 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=20 / lookahead-slices=8 / scenecut=40 / hist-scenecut=0 / radl=0 / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / ctu=64 / min-cu-size=8 / no-rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / rdoq-level=0 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=3 / limit-refs=1 / no-limit-modes / me=1 / subme=2 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / no-frame-dup / no-hme / weightp / no-weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / deblock=0:0 / sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=3 / selective-sao=4 / early-skip / rskip / no-fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / b-intra / no-splitrd-skip / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=0.00 / no-rd-refine / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / rc=crf / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / vbv-maxrate=160000 / vbv-bufsize=160000 / vbv-init=0.9 / min-vbv-fullness=50.0 / max-vbv-fullness=80.0 / crf-max=0.0 / crf-min=0.0 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=2 / aq-strength=1.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=1 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=2 / transfer=2 / colormatrix=2 / chromaloc=0 / display-window=0 / cll=0,0 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=1023 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / hist-threshold=0.03 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / no-hdr10 / no-hdr10-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=0 / analysis-save-reuse-level=0 / analysis-load-reuse-level=0 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=1 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0 / no-lowpass-dct / refine-analysis-type=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-dynamic-refine / no-single-sei / no-hevc-aq / no-svt / no-field / qp-adaptation-range=1.00 / scenecut-aware-qp=0conformance-window-offsets / right=0 / bottom=0 / decoder-max-rate=0 / no-vbv-live-multi-pass
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Color range                              : Limited
```